# C++ Area of Shape: Getting Area 0

Tags: c++

The Area of triangle and area off rectangle is 0 in the code below. Need some tips on how can i remove this problem.
also, if i can get some fixation on this, it would be great!

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

class shape
{
protected:
    double x,y;

public:
    void get_data(void);
    virtual void display_area(void){ }
};

class triangle:public shape
{
protected:
    double AoT;

public:
    void display_area(void);

};

class rectangle:public shape
{
protected:
    double AoR;

public:
    void display_area(void);

};

void shape::get_data(void)
{
    cout<<"Enter the vlaue of Base(x) and Height(y):"<<endl;
    cin>>x>>y;
}

void triangle::display_area(void)
{
    AoT=0.5*x*y;
    cout<<"The area of Triangle in unit sq. is:"<<AoT<<endl;
}

void rectangle::display_area(void)
{
    AoR=x*y;
    cout<<"The area of Rectangle in Unit sq. is:"<<AoR<<endl;
}

main()
{
    clrscr();
    shape s, *p;
    triangle t;
    rectangle r;

    s.get_data();
    p=&t;
    p->display_area();
    p=&r;
    p->display_area();

    getch();

}
```

Thanks in advanced. Need quick fixation on this because i',m kinda despo lol

Comment: x and y are my input @cad

Comment: `t` and `p` are not affected by input for `s`.

Comment: @mikeCAT please elaborate!

Comment: "Thanks in advanced" is spelt wrong, and wtf is "i',m kinda despo lol" jesus

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - and spelt grows in fields..

Comment: @devlincarnate: It's also the past participle of "to spell", in civilised countries.

Comment: @lightnessRacesinorbit I was frustrated because it showed me an error while posting this which was "code is long, please explain more" or something like that.. that's why i wrote all that.. Sorry.

Comment: @Anuj: Right, it said "please explain more", not "please add random chatter".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what more could I would've wrote when I already had explained my problem in the first line? :|

Comment: You stated it, very very briefly. You did not explain it, nor tell us the steps you took to resolve it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I got it.. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`s`, `t`, and `r` are completely unrelated objects. Calling `s.get_data()` only modifies `s.x` and `s.y`, neither `t.x` and `t.y` nor `r.x` and `r.y`. You need to call `shape::get_data` for `t` and `r` seperately:

```
p=&t;
p->get_data();
p->display_area();

p->get_data();
p=&r;
p->display_area();
```